# AWS s3 create folder using batch script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-powershell

I have created a batch script using the aws cmdline in windows however it doesn't seems to be running from my machine. IT does run from one of the server in our infra. IF i just run the aws s3api command from my machine it runs fine.

```
aws configure set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID <Access_key>
aws configure set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY <secret_key>
aws configure set default.region us-east-1
set /p key="Enter key:"
aws s3api put-object --bucket <bucket_name> --key %key%
```

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be running" - do you get an error?  Does the machine you're running this on catch fire?  Can you give us some more details?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on your local machine you can go to ~/.aws/credentials in your terminal and see there are your configured profiles. Typically you have a profile that is name [default] in which by default all of your aws calls etc will get ran with those keys and their respective permissions.

If your aws configure is not being set properly then your aws commands will try and execute under that [default] profile.